# What is the difference between download with resume and download without it?

Tags: web-services, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I need a short explanation about download with resume and download without resume.

What is the difference between these files on the server?

The reason is about protocol, ip or files type?

thanks...

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? Examples?

Comment: You mean 'resume' like if the download is stopped or interrupted it finishes where it left off rather than restarting the entire download?

Comment: yes, i mean that, I want to know why some files can be resume and other not?

Comment: Its not a matter of file type, but of app programming. for small files, allowing resume would be painful and wouldn't give you any advantage in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download with resume just means that the byte stream containing the attachment can be stopped, and whatever has been recieved will be saved locally. when the download is resumed, the client asks the server to start teh stream at a specified index to download the remainder of the stream. without resume, the client would have to download the entire file, redownloading any data they had previously saved.

This interaction occures at the webserver level and has nothing to do with specific communication/networking protocols, file types, etc. its just that the service and the client has a way to interact that allows partial downloads with resumption.

here is a somewhat dated article on how to do partial downloads with resume in ASP.net 1.1, just to give you some of the flavor of it:
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22533

Comment: thanks for that... do you have some article source about computer networks... for example: different between connection oriented and connection less... different between ftp and tftp

Comment: here is a comparision between TCP (connection orriented) and UDP (connectionless): http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP

Comment: as for the differance between HTTP and FTP, its all about command syntax. both protocols use TCP as their connection medium, and issue commands in text like 'GET /public/news.html \nHTTP1.1\n', which gets a response like '200 <!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hello</body></html>'. FTP uses a simmilar command syntax, but the commands all use verbs like GET and PUT. in HTTP, the command commands are GET and POST. Hope that helps.

Comment: @PoyaEraghi What does 'connected/connectedless' have to do with 'with/without resume'? What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

> need a short explanation about download with resume and download without resume.

With resume, you can resume. Without it, you can't.

> What is the different between these files on the server.

What files? What server? Download with/without resume doesn't affect the files at all, it affects the download processs.

This is barely a real question. It's just about the meaning of the words, which is self-evident.

Comment: TNX, Do not bother yourself too much...